# Why are Landsat 8 files on AWS compressed cf those from USGS?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat-8, usgs, amazon-web-services, earth-explorer

I want to shift from downloading Landsat8 imagery directly from USGS to the AWS service (https://pages.awscloud.com/public-data-sets-landsat.html).

I have some automated processes that are not accepting the TIF files from AWS. Upon closer inspection the file sizes differ substantially.

For example for scene LC80930842016347LGN00 if I download from EarthExplorer as LC80930842016347LGN00.tar.gz and extract all bands except B8 are 116,191KB.

When I download the bands individually from AWS (http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/L8/093/084/LC80930842016347LGN00/index.html) all bands except B8 are around 60MB and the BQA band is only about 1MB.

Is there some compression going on in the AWS storage and if so, is there a process to transform these back to original so the Landsat_LDOPE tools will work?

Comment: `gdalinfo` tells me the AWS tifs are DEFALTE compressed with 512x512 tiling.

Comment: According to the TIFF wiki article DEFLATE compression is lossless so we in theory should be able to convert back to original state?

Comment: So the answer to the question in the title is probably "because as DEFLATE compressed they take less disk space without loosing quality".

Answer (score 1):

AWS compresses GeoTiff using DEFLATE.

Running

```
gdal_translate LC80930842016347LGN00_B1.TIF LC80930842016347LGN00_B1_.TIF
```

returns uncompressed file exactly the same size as TIFs from USGS.

Comment: It may not be the compression, but the tiling that ldope chokes on. I suggest testing compressed without tiling as well.

Comment: Cheers, I'll try. Actually the ldope is still choking on my above solution, but Spectral Transformer is working again.